# Invalid token "=" when trying to make an audio source

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Having the usual invalid token "=" that I can usually fix. This time I cant wrap my head around about whats wrong. I'm a new, young programmer who is learning so this is probably really obvious but it would really help if you could reply thanks!

Here is the code thats wrong

```
audio = (AudioSource)AudioClip.AddComponent ("AudioSource");
AudioClip myAudioClip;
myAudioClip = (AudioClip)Resources.Load("SFX/DoNotQuestionTheAdventureVoice");
audio.clip = myAudioClip;
```

Here is the whole code if you need it:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Button : MonoBehaviour {
    public AudioSource audio;
    public AudioClip buttonSound;

    void Update(){}

    void start ();

    audio = (AudioSource)AudioClip.AddComponent ("AudioSource");
    AudioClip myAudioClip;
    myAudioClip = (AudioClip)Resources.Load("SFX/DoNotQuestionTheAdventureVoice");
    audio.clip = myAudioClip;


    void OnGUI () {
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (300, 300, 400, 50), "Do not question the adventure voice!")) {
                audio.Play ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is the error referring to, and what is on said line? Is `AudioClip.AddComponent` the culprit? Try changing to just `AddComponent`.

Comment: Its on the 1,3,4 line on the one that is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your code formatting is incorrect, but based on that, your code is inside your class declaration but looks like it should be inside the `start` method.

Reformatted and fixed code is below.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Button : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource audio;
    public AudioClip buttonSound;

    void Update()
    {
    }

    // Changed from start(); which is not valid
    // Also, this may need to be "Start" (note the difference in casing)
    void start()
    {
       audio = (AudioSource)AudioClip.AddComponent ("AudioSource");
       AudioClip myAudioClip;
       myAudioClip = (AudioClip)Resources.Load("SFX/DoNotQuestionTheAdventureVoice");
       audio.clip = myAudioClip;
    }

    void OnGUI ()
    {
        if (GUI.Button (new Rect (300, 300, 400, 50), "Do not question the adventure voice!")) {
        audio.Play ();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm back on track now! :)